# Exported Electron APP doesn't work on MacOS

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, electron

I created my first Electron Application and I'm ready to publish it. I was able to export it for these two platforms with no errors:

- Linux Debian
- Windows

But when I export it for MacOS, the `test.app` doesn't work.

I'm using MacOS HighSierra and I tested everything I could think of, but couldn't get my app to work on MacOS.

I'm not sure if I have to convert it to a `dmg` file before executing it, so I tested converting my app to `.dmg` using this guide:

https://kb.parallels.com/en/123895

But when I run the `dmg` and try to install the app, I get same errors again. I really tried everything but got no luck. I hope there is someone here that knows how to get it exported for MacOS.

To export the app I used the `electron-packager` and this is my `package.json`

```
   {
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "package-mac": "electron-packager . --overwrite --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/mac/icon.icns --prune=true --out=release-builds --app-copyright=\"test",
    "package-win": "electron-packager . test --overwrite --asar=true --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=assets/icons/win/icon.ico --prune=true --out=release-builds --version-string.CompanyName=CE --version-string.FileDescription=CE --version-string.ProductName=\"test\" --app-copyright=\"test\"",
    "package-linux": "electron-packager . test --overwrite --asar=true --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=assets/icons/png/icon.png --prune=true --out=release-builds --app-copyright=\"test"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "1.8.4",
    "electron-packager": "^9.0.1"
  }
}
```

And this is my Error Log when I try to run the `test.app` file on the Mac, that I had exported from Electron:

```
Process:               test [657]
Path:                  /Volumes/*/test.app/Contents/MacOS/test
Identifier:            com.electron.test
Version:               1.1.1 (1.1.1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           test [657]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2018-04-11 13:23:39.858 -0700
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.13 (17A291j)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        0CF5BE48-84D7-4216-9DC6-58685E649DDD


Time Awake Since Boot: 550 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/Electron Framework.framework/Electron Framework
  Referenced from: /Volumes/*/test.app/Contents/MacOS/test
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Volumes/VMware Shared Folders/dev/test.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/Electron Framework.framework/  Electron Framework: file too short
    /Volumes/VMware Shared Folders/dev/app/release/test-darwin-x64/test.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/   Electron Framework.framework/Electron Framework: stat() failed with errno=1

Binary Images:
       0x103f99000 -        0x103f99ff7 +com.electron.test (1.1.1 - 1.1.1) <    C11B8E11-EDD2-37B9-9AB5-5FE9E97FFFFB> /Volumes/*/test.app/Contents/MacOS/test
       0x10d97a000 -        0x10d9c237f  dyld (513.2) <CEB3F2DA-93CF-3991-AD98-582FAF7023AB> /usr/lib/dyld
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the source code is running properly with `npm start` on mac machine then it is an **electron-packager** issue. I would suggest you to try to make a build using **electron-builder**.

Note: You will need a mac machine to make a .dmg build.

See the configuration of [zulip/zulip-electron](https://github.com/zulip/zulip-electron/blob/f70432f4e3cdc86ae610bf3d77bfa2e784fabdf3/package.json#L39)

Comment: Thanks so much! Yeah, it was an error with **electron-packager** after switching to **electron-builder** I was able to export it to mac with no issues :)

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the crash issue repeatedly when launching an app on Mac .

The reason for the crash turned out to be permissions issue on some of the Electron framework folders. 
The folders had 744 permission and `root` as owner, because of which the logged in user was not able to execute the framework files . 
Changing the permission to 755 for the folder fixed the issue for me.